# Custom Post Type archive redirects to home

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect

I have a custom post type and I can't access the archive page for it. When I try to it redirects me to the home page. I don't have any taxonomy for it. I have setup an archive-post-type.php template for it though.

I can access the individual posts in that post type.

I've re-saved my permalinks, deleted my htaccess file and resaved my permalinks again. Still redirects. Any ideas?

UPDATE: It's working when I try it in another browser, but Chrome continues to redirect. Cleared my cache, but it's still happening.

Here is my code for my custom post type.

```
register_post_type(
    'featured-grants',
    array(
        'description'         => '',
        'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 6,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-awards',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'delete_with_user'    => false,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,

        /* The rewrite handles the URL structure. */
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'       => 'featured-grants',
            'with_front' => true,
            'pages'      => true,
            'feeds'      => true,
            'ep_mask'    => EP_PERMALINK,
        ),

        /* What features the post type supports. */
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail'
        ),

        /* Labels used when displaying the posts. */
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => __( 'Featured Grants',                   'featured-grants' ),
            'singular_name'      => __( 'Featured Grant',                    'featured-grants' ),
            'menu_name'          => __( 'Featured Grants',                  'featured-grants' ),
            'name_admin_bar'     => __( 'Featured Grants',          'featured-grants' ),
            'add_new'            => __( 'Add New',                    'featured-grants' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Featured Grant',            'featured-grants' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Featured Grant',               'featured-grants' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Featured Grant',                'featured-grants' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Featured Grant',               'featured-grants' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Featured Grants',            'featured-grants' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No featured grants found',          'featured-grants' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No featured grants found in trash', 'featured-grants' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'Featured Grants',                   'featured-grants' ),
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: What URL are you attempting to visit as the archive page?  Can you view individual posts in this post type, if so, what is the URL structure?

Comment: @jdm2112 I'm accessing at /featured-grants . I can access the individual posts in it. They are at /featured-grants/post-name

Comment: What action are you hooked to when you register your post type?

Comment: @jdm2112 So it's working, but just not in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue, cleared cache in chrome multiple times and closed it.